# Java multiple class definitions in the same file

Tags: java, access-modifiers

just a simple question, if you have the following code in a file called Example.java:

```
package MyPackage;

public class Example{
   void foo(){}
   ...
   ...
}

class A{}
class B{}
```

what is the modifier of the class A and B?

Comment: Just don't do it.  Put each class in its own file.

Comment: The question does not really depend on them being all in one file, though. The answer would be the same if they were in different files.

Answer (score 5):

They have the default modifier, which means package-private.
[See here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: They cannot be private as the link you give states.  A top-level class can only be default or public, and there can only be one public top-level class.

Answer (score 4):

They are both default visibility (package private).

- [Controlling Access to Members of a Class (Java Tutorial)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)